# What if we don't use Database.LeadConvert and manually create Account, Contact and Opp and update the Lead?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, lead-conversion

I saw this practice in one of the orgs. They had done this using flows. I believe this is not the best practice having Salesforce OOTB way to convert the Leads.

Are there any issues associated with not using Database.LeadConvert for auto-converting the leads?

Any documentation links to support why it's recommended use Database.LeadConvert for auto lead conversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not using a lead conversion feature may cause a loss of data. For example, converting the lead using `Database.convertLead` or through the UI will make sure that any activities and campaign information are copied to the account, contact, and/or opportunity, as appropriate, while just creating the records may leave some data left behind in the lead record. In addition, the `ConvertedAccountId`, `ConvertedContactId`, and `ConvertedOpportunityId` fields won't be set correctly. This also makes some kinds of reports, such as Campaign ROI or lead conversion reports, less useful/accurate. In short, conversion should be done with the appropriate methods.

Comment: +1 Additionally, When a lead is converted through the standard way, its link will be automatically redirected to the respective contact if someone tries to access the lead using its ID based URL.